# Artifacts on the top and bottom of png textures in THREE.js v76

Tags: three.js

I'm getting some [artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns2r2.png) on the [top and bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wmAV.png) sides on some of my sprites. [These are the shaders](http://hastebin.com/hanucekose.cpp) I am using, if that matters. I'm using v76.

And I'm building these sprites like this:

```
var object = new THREE.Object3D();
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.load('path/to/image.png', function(texture) {
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.anisotropy = 16;
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(15, 15);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: texture,
        color: 0xffffff,
        transparent: true,
        alphaTest: 0.2,
        side: DoubleSide,
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    mesh.customDepthMaterial = new ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: { texture: { type: 't', value: this.material.map } },
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
    });
    object.add(mesh);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set your textures to wrap with `THREE.RepeatWrapping`. This can leave artifacts on texture edges meant to be used as sprites.

Comment: i couldn't fix it even with your advice, although i ended up with a mix of your answer and playing around with the alphaTest and values in the shaders until they "dissapeared" enough to not be so visible